# Smoothing of GPS tracks - remove noise and stop-go clusters

Tags: r, kalman-filter, smoothing

[image]I know there are several posts about this, but I could not find exactly what I need. I have GPS track data (from an underwater vehicle) for short intervals of 1 second (time-stamps on data). The data are noisy and especially when the vehicle stops the track becomes messy. I'd like to smooth the track to calculate a realistic travelled length of the track (in the way it is described here https://www.gpsvisualizer.com/tutorials/track_filters.html), ideally implementing in R. The picture illustrates what I need.

I have tried the RDP: The Ramer-Douglas-Peucker Algorithm function, but this does either totally oversmooth or keep those areas where the vehicle stops and there are dense data. This is how my data looks like (there is about 3000 data points for a track of ca. 500m).

```
head(track)

      id                date lc      lon      lat

1 ROV_24 2021-04-21 08:28:00  G 17.23895 68.75293
2 ROV_24 2021-04-21 08:28:01  G 17.23895 68.75293
3 ROV_24 2021-04-21 08:28:02  G 17.23895 68.75293
4 ROV_24 2021-04-21 08:28:03  G 17.23895 68.75293
5 ROV_24 2021-04-21 08:28:04  G 17.23895 68.75293
6 ROV_24 2021-04-21 08:28:05  G 17.23896 68.75293
```